# Can't copy formula?

Tags: vba, formula

I can't operate the code without it stating the sub or function is not defined in the formula I'm trying to paste down column v.

```
Sub SEALANTSCHEDULIZER()
'    1. Unhide All Columns
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

'    2. Clear All color highlights
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 0

'    3. Drag formulas in all columns down to last row (if necessary) – use column A (ID) as row count
LastRowColumnA = cell(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("V2:V" & LastRowColumnA).Formula = "=IF(OR(W2="Yes", AE2="Yes"), "Yes", "No")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double the `"` around the text strings.

```
"=IF(OR(W2=""Yes"", AE2=""Yes""), ""Yes"", ""No"")"
```